# SpringBootでのWhitelabel Error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

SpringBootで
localhost:8080/hello
で遷移可能なページを作りたいのですが、
上記リクエストを飛ばすとWhitelabel Errorになってしまいます。

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"></meta>
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </body>

</html>


package com.example.demo.hello;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class HelloController {
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String getHello() {
        // hello.htmlに画面遷移
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

何が原因なのか検討がつかず、お力添えをいただければ幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

質問文中の情報に限って言えば、特に問題はありません。
従って、原因は質問文に書かれていない部分にあると言えます。
(情報が書かれていないので想像になりますが)次のどれかが本来あるべき姿と異なっているのではないでしょうか。

---

プロジェクトの依存関係(`pom.xml`あるいは`build.gradle`の内容)とディレクトリ構成が正しい必要があります。

- (典型的には)依存関係に Spring Web(`spring-boot-starter-web`) と Thymeleaf(`spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf`)　が含まれている必要があります
- `hello.html` は `src/main/resources/templates/` ディレクトリに保存する必要があります

[公式チュートリアル](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/)(の[非公式日本語訳](https://spring.pleiades.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/)) に同等のことを行っているものがありますのでこちらも参考にしてみてください。